# Android: offline dictionary

Tags: android, database, sqlite, dictionary, android-asynctask

I am developing a dictionary application which stores the database offline. Now the problem is I am using autocomplete textview to display suggestions. As I type the suggestions should be loaded. If I don't use AsyncTask the typing becomes really slow and it gives a lag. And if I use AsyncTask the, still the suggestions take too much of time to load from database. Meaning the database search query is really slow and does not display results quickly. Please help me as I am stuck on this for quite a long time. My code is as below. Thanks in advance.

```
        autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    results = db.getWords(s.toString());//arraylist
                    return null;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    adapter.addAll(results);
                }
            }.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            query.showDropDown();
        }
```

I am doing everything in `onTextChanged()`. Here is my sqlite query for searching the results.`"SELECT WORD FROM tblWords WHERE Word LIKE '%s%%' GROUP BY Word LIMIT 5"`. Note that the database is extremely large. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, are you testing this on an emulator or on an actual android device?

Comment: Just curious: are you aware that `you already have this project in your SDK samples folder`? It's called **searchable dictionary**. Version **2** uses a db instead of a text file.

Comment: Just to clarify: the results you get are accurate, and the only problem is that it's too slow? And how slow exactly?

Comment: yes the results are just as I need. The problem being it takes some time to load the results in async task and so the results are not displayed in the drop down of auto complete textview.

Comment: @DerGolem I dont know about the version 2 you are talking. Can you provide a link?

Comment: Look in `[Eclipse installation path]\sdk\samples\android-19\legacy\SearchableDictionary` (which appears to be identical to `[Eclipse installation path]\sdk\samples\android-8\SearchableDictionary`)

Comment: ... The project isn't finished (red error markers!) until you add the `support library v4`, (optionally?) change the target version to 4.3 (or 4.x, whatever) and add a depedency to `app-compat-v7`. Ready, GO.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein , is searchable dictionary, an incomplete database, because in the sample app I cannot find many words, or is there a way of displaying all the words.

Comment: This one is meant to be just an example. Then, you can develop your app around this one.

Answer (score 2):

I notice two things:

You have no minimum length to start searching. I would think that normally it doesn't make a lot of sense to start searching at 1 or 2 characters, partly because you would get way too many results. It's also possible it starts searching at 0 characters, so perhaps it's trying to add your complete database to the adapter.

Another thing I notice is that you never clear the collection of the adapter, but only add everything. This will also bloat the list with unnecessary results.

A last note is style-related: I wouldn't use the addAll method, but instead update the list used by the Adapter and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. I think this is just style, but perhaps it would also increase performance.

Comment: Notifydatasetchanged() is not working and the adapter shows count 0 so I used addAll() method. And as I am LIMITing the results of query by 5 it does not add the entire database.